# Extract facebook users IDs who like or comment a post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql, facebook-php-sdk

I wonder if anyone knows or has a tool which allows to extract the list of users IDs who liked or commented a Facebook post (especially a page post).

I've tried many softwares that claim performing this task in vain...

If you have a miracle, please share the love. I'd be glad to have either a software name, a java script, or anything that can do so.

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Would you mind telling what are you going to do with this?

Answer
`263907926200` is the sample post id used

Through browser

```
https://graph.facebook.com/263907926200/comments
https://graph.facebook.com/263907926200/likes
```

Through API Explorer

```
->/v2.2/263907926200/comments
->/v2.2/263907926200/likes
```

**FQL Method if you have an old app**

**Likes**
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT user_id FROM like WHERE post_id = "xxxxx_xxxxx"
**Comments**
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT fromid FROM comment WHERE post_id ="xxxxx_xxxxx"